# Ubuntu 16.04 suspends even though battery setting is set to "Don't suspend"

Tags: 16.04, suspend

I am currently studying for three exams and have the old exams on my computer screen, however, to my greatest annoyance the screen keeps going dark even though the setting is set to not do that. Anyone now how to fix this bug?

Comment: Did you set the settings in *System Settings* -> *Brightness & Lock* -> *Turn off screen when inactive for* to either **1 hour** or **Never**? If that doesn't work it's probably a bug.

Answer (score 3):

**Suspension and turning off the screen due to inactivity are different and independent settings.**

Your question mentions the former but refers to the latter.

At **Brightness & Lock** is where the screen behavior is set. Use the settings shown for your intended behavior.

PS - NOT a bug!

[image]